# How can we get the jenkins console output in a text file?

Tags: jenkins

How can i get the Jenkins console output in a text file?
I want to share it with someone, is there any way to do it?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018509/jenkinsfile-build-log

Answer (score 41, accepted):

if you want just access the log and download it as a txt file to your workspace from the job's URL:

```
${BUILD_URL}/consoleText
```

On Linux, you can use `wget` to download it to your workspace

```
wget ${BUILD_URL}/consoleText
```

The actual log file on the file system is in the Master machine. You can find it under:

`$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/$JOB_NAME/builds/lastSuccessfulBuild/log`

Comment: Also use `$WORKSPACE`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had to open a full console output via browser, but it was very big, my browser cannot handle it. You can change the last part of the URL from `consoleFull` to `consoleText` as noted above. While the browser is loading it, you can hit `CTRL+S` to save it as a txt file and open it in notepad++.

Or as noted above, use wget or curl which should be available if you have git for windows installed (for windows users).

Answer (score 4):

For Windows you could use `curl` in a powershell prompt:

```
curl  ${BUILD_URL}\consoleText -OutFile C:\SomeLocation\SomeFile.txt
```

For MacOS:

```
curl  ${BUILD_URL}/consoleText -o /SomeLocation/SomeFile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the Jenkins console log without curl or wget:

```
writeFile file: "jenkins_console_output.txt", text: currentBuild.rawBuild.logFile.text
sh 'sed -ri "s/\\x1b\\[8m.*?\\x1b\\[0m//g" jenkins_console_output.txt'
```

Explanation:

- `currentBuild.rawBuild.logFile.text` will return [annotated log](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/console/ConsoleAnnotator.html).
- `\x1b\[8m.*?\x1b\[0m` is a regex expression to match AnsiColorer
- `sed -ri` use regexp-extended and in-place to update the file